# Django PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python, django

I upload files to Google Drive by uploading files to the system first and then to Google Drive, after that I immediately delete them from website directory in one process. But here I get an error.

I'm not deleting files on google drive but deleting files in the website directory.

**views.py**

```
tfile = request.FILES['file']

temp = db.FileTemp(files=tfile)
temp.save()

media_metadata = {
  'name': str(tfile),
  'parents': [folder.objects.filter(user__username=user)[0].id_folder]
}
media = MediaFileUpload(os.path.join(temp.files.path), mimetype='image/jpeg', resumable=True)
upfile = drive.files().create(body=media_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()

user_permission = {
   'type': 'anyone',
   'role': 'reader',
}
perm = drive.permissions().create(fileId=upfile.get('id'), body=user_permission).execute()
link = drive.files().get(fileId=upfile.get('id'), fields='webViewLink').execute()

result['status'] = True
result['link'] = link['webViewLink']
            
temp.delete()
```

**models.py**

```
class FileTemp(models.Model):
    files = models.FileField(upload_to="file")

@receiver(post_delete, sender=FileTemp)
def foto_file_delete_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    filed = kwargs['instance']
    storage, path = filed.files.storage, filed.files.path
    storage.delete(path)
```

Comment: What package are you using for calling Google Drive's API?

Comment: I used `googleapiclient` with default syntax from google drive's API